# Detecting url in a text with HTTPS format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatadetector

Here is my code to detect URL in a text

```
let detector: NSDataDetector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = detector.matches(in: message!, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, (message?.count)!))
var url: URL?
for item in matches {
    let match = item as NSTextCheckingResult
    url = match.url
    print(url!)
    break
}
```

However, this code makes www.example.com as http://example.com

What I want is to get this URL as HTTPS like https://example.com

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What’s the value of `message`?

Comment: @rmaddy www.example.com

Comment: If the string is just the URL why bother with a data detector?

Comment: Because I need to get site name, image and description from the url and send it to chat backend

Comment: It is not always an url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API to tell `NSDataDetector` to default to `https` URL schemes when it finds a URL with no scheme.

One option is to update the resulting URL yourself:

```
let message = "www.example.com"
let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: message, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: message.utf16.count))
var url: URL?
for match in matches {
    if match.resultType == .link {
        url = match.url
        if url?.scheme == "http" {
            if var urlComps = URLComponents(url: url!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
                urlComps.scheme = "https"
                url = urlComps.url
            }
        }
        print(url)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this would also replace URL with an explicit http scheme with https scheme.